# facebox 1.3 not to close the dialog when you click outside of the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, facebox, frontend

Facebox 1.3 has this feature different than the prior version, in which if you click outside of the modal window, it makes it to fade out. I have a form that loads with an AJAX call and is using jQuery Validation plugin to prevent it from loading. Any ideas how to prevent this behavior? I like the looks of the new version way much more...

I have posted this into Google groups for this topic and no answer yet, so I don't know what else to try.. any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

The Facebox JS is at: http://defunkt.io/facebox/

removing completely the overlay does not do it for me... but more importantly.. is this valid at all?

```
  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
  $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
$('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
  $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
  $('#facebox .loading').remove()
  $(document).trigger('afterClose.facebox')

  $('#facebox').find('form').each('div.formError').hide();
```

//I want to remove each of those divs when it closes the facebox... using it with jQuery Validation Engine

```
})
hideOverlay()
})
```

Comment: Solved it using the following to hide the Error Messages when closing Facebox -->    $('.formError').fadeOut("fast", function() {
    $(this).parent('.formErrorOuter').remove();
    $(this).remove();
     })
          at the last bind that triggers such event, request to close please.

Comment: To not allow Facebox to close the overlay when clicking on it (outside of the modal Facebox 1.3 dialog) -->     $('#facebox_overlay').hide().addClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      .css('opacity', $.facebox.settings.opacity)
      .click(function() { return false;})
      .fadeIn(200)
    return false
  }

Comment: Good question.+1 (facing the same problem)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).bind('loading.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox');
    $('#facebox_overlay').unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: [**what should a minimal answer contain**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain)

Comment: After multiple search i got this code and it worked like a charm for me.+1.